# Announcer badge not received

Tags: support, badges

I shared a questions with high views more than once but never received the Announcer badge.

I even shared the same question someone had his badge by sharing it and still didn't receive mine!

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 6):

Are you using the proper share links? They look like this:

```
http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8835/449
```

The segment on the end is my user ID on Ask Ubuntu. That's how the link is tracked back to my account when somebody clicks it. That's how the badge is earnt.

To rephrase, if you're just sharing the full links (like the one you see in the browser address bar: `http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8835/announcer-badge-not-received`) you're not going to get the badge.

As Dan also points out in the comments, each visit to a valid URL needs to be a different IP from the others to count as a unique visitor. So even if you have a thousand real people click the link, if they're all using the same IP address, the system counts them as one. Same goes if you click the link a thousand times. This is crude but we are only talking about a badge here.

Comment: I use the **Share** hyperlink under the question.

Comment: I rechecked and it is indeed the correct format Example : "http://askubuntu.com/q/440193/142902"

Comment: @Ahmadgeo It also counts unique IP, so I believe if you share it with people under the same network (which is under a NAT), you won't get the badge, since they would all count as 1.

Answer (score 3):

The announcer badge tracks unique IP addresses following *your **share** link*.  If people are not following the link then people are not going to get the badge.

[image]

The share link on this question (for example) gives me:

```
http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8835/153310
```

which is made up of a few parts:

```
http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8835/153310
                            ^    ^ My user ID
                            |
                            +-- The question ID
```

Somewhere, in the DBs of stack exchange there is a table that looks roughly like:

```
AnnouncerCandidate
------------------
User ID
Question ID
IP address
```

Every time someone follows the shared link a new row is added to the table (if possible - duplicate rows aren't added).  When the there are 25 rows for a given `User ID / Question ID` combo, the announcer badge is awarded.

Furthermore, these scripts are not run constantly.  See MSO [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated) so even if you know the 25th person clicked your link *now*, it may take a day or more to get the badge.

Sharing post that someone else got an announcer for does not mean that you will get the announcer too.  Sharing currently high view questions doesn't mean yuo will get the announcer either. This is entirely dependent on individual people clicking through the link that you provided them with your user id in it.